# What color is Stormlight?

Tags: magic, cosmere, stormlight-archive

> Dalinar began to pant, and when he moved quickly, he left trails of **blue stormlight** in the air.

From *Way of Kings* Chapter 56, page 977 of my edition. And then, 14 pages later in Chapter 57:

> All five gemstones had been drained.The **white light** streaming from Kaladin's skin faintly illuminated the inside of the bag.

What color is stormlight?

Comment: Bluish white? Unless Dalinar's color light is coming from the gems in his armor.

Comment: yeah i always thought it was mostly white, but easily tinged by your armor.

Comment: Rythm of War tells a lot about colors of various rosharan lights and many properties.

Answer (score 4):

Stormlight is exactly what it sounds like. Light.

Kaladin's light is not changed by anything. Dalinar was wearing a shard plate which I think had sapphires inlaid in them. The light coming through the plate would be blue, because they are coming from the blue stones.

Comment: Do you have any sources for anything?

Answer (score 2):

After I posted this I got really curious and began poking around to see what I could find.

In an AMA on Reddit in 2013 (which I found [here](http://www.theoryland.com/intvsresults.php?kwt='gemstones')), Sanderson mentioned how the color of gemstones matters for Surgebinding.  This is what he said:

> A gemstone with an impure color would be considered like a bad alloy in the Mistborn magic—it either wouldn't work at all, or would work very poorly. The chemical and color signature needs to be of a specific variety to provide the proper key to accessing the power of transformation.

This makes sense; after all, the gemstones of a Soulcaster do different things for each stone.  If the color of the gems matter, they may give off different types/colors of Stormlight, like different metals in Mistborn.

[Here](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/TheStormlightArchive)(WARNING TV TROPES) I found this:

> When infused with Stormlight, they glow; the brightness and color of the light depends on the size and type of gemstone, respectively.

I haven't found Brandon confirming this, but I have found several questions about an Awakener messing with the color of gemstones/stormlight.

Since different gemstones of different colors--and the colors do seem to matter--do different things via Surgebinding, I think that the color of stormlight does in fact depend on the gemstone.

---

EDIT:
Found some quotes that illustrate this hypothesis further.
First from WoK Chapter 37:

> The vestibule inside had a low ceiling and was decorated with ceramics; zircon spheres gave them a pale blue cast.

In WoR Chapter 86 it is shown that diamonds shine with a white light.  (Don't have a quote, I found this in a citation on the [wiki](http://stormlightarchive.wikia.com/wiki/Gemstone).

Answer (score 1):

Stormlight is light, it doesn't have a color inherently (or rather is white), but once it is in a gem (either sphere, fabrial, or shardplate), it becomes that color (as may be expected).

> When she opened the money pouch, **shards of ruby, emerald, diamond, and sapphire shone out** on her face.
> <sub>*The Way of Kings - Chapter 3: City of Bells*</sub>

> Other occupied alcoves **glowed with different colors from the spheres being used to light them**; the darkness of the huge space made them seem to hover in the air.
> <sub>*The Way of Kings - Chapter 7: Anything Reasonable*</sub>

> “Well, I suppose I should be leading you back to the ship, then,” Yalb said, reluctantly gathering up the spheres in the pile at his feet. **They glowed with a variety of hues.** Their light was small—each was only a chip—but it was impressive winnings.
> <sub>*The Way of Kings - Chapter 8: Nearer the Flame*</sub>

> There, she used all her remaining spheres to fill the oversized goblet lamp. To get enough light, she was forced to use **spheres of all nine colors** and all three sizes, so the illumination was patchy and varied.
> <sub>*The Way of Kings - Chapter 8: Nearer the Flame*</sub>

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

When in a person (or a clearmark), Stormlight is white.

> It was dark inside. All five gemstones had been drained. The white light streaming from Kaladin’s skin faintly illuminated the inside of the bag.
> <sub>*The Way of Kings - Chapter 57: Wandersail*</sub>

So basically it operates exactly like light in the real world.

Here is a cheat sheet for the gems and the colors they give off.

| Gem | Color |
| --- | --- |
| Sapphire | Blue |
| Smokestone | Unknown (only described as "light". perhaps white) |
| Ruby | Red |
| Diamond | White |
| Emerald | Green |
| Garnet | Red |
| Zircon | Blue |
| Amethyst | Violet |
| Topaz | Orange |
| Heliodor | Yellow |